# How to pass string as a read stream object in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

Im trying multi import functionality for a 3rd party api, where i need to pass a json file read stream.

But i'm already having an array of user data in my api which i need to pass as a read stream.

Options i have already tried.

1. `fs.createReadStream`

`fs.createReadStream(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify('[{ user: "data"}]')));`

> createReadStream not accepting Buffer & returns
>
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

2. `require('stream').Readable`

   `const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    const readStream = new Readable();
    readStream._read = () => {};
    readStream.push(JSON.stringify(u));
    readStream.push(null);`

> Read stream gives me "Invalid multipart payload format" error in my request

Please find the request object which i pass for multi user file upload

```
{
  "url": "",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {},
  "formData": {
    "userFile": ReadStream
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciatable

Answer (score 1):

You can create a readable stream from a string like this:

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';
// OR: const { Readable } = require('stream');

const stream = Readable.from("This is the stream content");
```

Comment: It's wrong, because author asked how to create ReadStream for `fs` which extends base ReadStream of Node.js. If you would use your approach, then for TypeScript it would raise errors: `Type 'Readable' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadStream': close, bytesRead, path, pending`. `fs.ReadStream` !== `Readable`

Comment: @PatrykMilewski I don't think so, I can't see where the author asked for `fs.ReadStream` and their second example shows them using `Readable`.  No library should use `fs.ReadStream` instead of `Readable`, if so it is a bug and should be reported so it can be fixed.